# Finding Kentucky records from 1800 to 1900?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, death-records, will, kentucky

I am researching various families in Kentucky from 1800 through 1900.

All the online resources have census stuff but when looking for more details I hit nothing.

Where online can you find Kentucky death, wills, land, etc records?

Specifically Hitt's, Holtzclaw, Bratton, and Asbury families.

I cannot pay for every scrap with no results.

Answer (score 8):

Have you looked at what's available on [FamilySearch](https://familysearch.org/search/collection/list#page=1&countryId=36)? They're always a good starting point.

[Cyndi's List](http://www.cyndislist.com/us/ky/) may also lead you to some resources you can access free or during an unpaid trial period at various sites. If you're organised, free trial periods can be very useful.

Answer (score 6):

You might check out the [Kentucky Probate Records](https://familysearch.org/search/image/index#uri=https://familysearch.org/recapi/sord/collection/1875188/waypoints) on FamilySearch.  These are images of scans of the original records.  (The index is not complete.)

I've found my ancestors just scanning through the records for the counties and dates where they lived.  Many of my finds were when people were listed on the estate sale for someone else -  their name and what they bought and the price they paid.  I was able to verify one ancestor's middle initial and for another prove they were living up to a certain date.